# Determine the users TokenSize

Tags: c#, active-directory

Is this an acceptable way to determine a users TokenSize:

```
    //TokenSize = 1200 + 40d + 8s
    //http://support.microsoft.com/kb/327825/en-us
    int TSize = 1200;
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity
        (new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Environment.UserDomainName), IdentityType.SamAccountName, Environment.UserName);
    foreach (GroupPrincipal group in user.GetGroups())
    {
        if (group.IsSecurityGroup == true)
            if (group.GroupScope == GroupScope.Global)
                TSize = TSize + 8;
            else
                TSize = TSize + 40;
    }
```

What about SIDHistory?  How can they be tallied?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The KB already told you that it's an estimated value.  It was used as a guideline for the system admin to set the MaxTokenSize registry key.

```
This formula uses the following values:

    d: The number of domain local groups a user is a member of plus the number of universal groups outside the user's account domain plus the number of groups represented in security ID (SID) history.
    s: The number of security global groups that a user is a member of plus the number of universal groups in a user's account domain.
    1200: The estimated value for ticket overhead. This value can vary depending on factors such as DNS domain name length, client name, and other factors.

In scenarios in which delegation is used (for example, when users authenticate to a domain controller), Microsoft recommends that you double the token size.
```

Why do you need to calculate the token size?  Just want to make sure you didn't mix this up with process token.

The token here means the Kerberos ticket or NTLM token which are normally cached and maintained by SSP.  Since it's a very sensitive piece of information, it's highly protected and you normally cannot access it from your user mode application.  The token the application normally deal with is the process token, which is different from the token described by this KB.  However, it's true that the Kerberos ticket or NTLM token carries a lot of authorization information, which ultimately used to generate the process token.  I don't recall there is a maximum token size limit on the process token.  I might be wrong though.

About the *SidHistory* question, I am not sure I get what you mean.  Here is my understanding.  The token contains a list of group SID, which may come from *SidHistory* from the AD group object.  The token itself doesn't need to know whether the group SID is from *SidHistory* or *objectSid*.  In case your application needs to look up the AD group object from the TOKEN_GROUPS information stored in the token, your application needs to do the query against *objectSid* as well as *sidHistory*

Comment: It’s about the Kerberos token. We have reached, and partially exceeded the MaxTokenSize for some users since we began migrating to a new forest using SID-History.  I need the user to run a script, showing him that he could potentially run into problems, and should contact support.  I need as accurate a size as possible to keep the users working “trouble free” and not over stress the support.  Is there a way, “just” to look at the users Token, to determine the size?

Comment: I see.  In that case, what I would suggest is that you can use [GetTokenInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446671%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the TOKEN_GROUPS of your access token.  Then, use [UserPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.aspx) to find the group membership using LDAP.  Compare the group lists.  If there are any difference, then, your token is trimmed.  Be careful to handle those built in group specially.  I think this is the most reliable way.

Comment: I can’t figure out, how to get hold of TOKEN_GROUPS… and unfortunately the  UserPrincipal’s „GetGroups()“ method does not retrieve the groups which SIDHhistory puts the user in.

Comment: If `UserPrincipals.GetGroups()` doesn't honor SIDhistory, you can try to retrieve the `tokenGroups` attribute directly from the AD user object.  It's a computed attribute maintained by AD.  Not sure how I can help you on TOKEN_GROUPS.  Google "GetTokenInformation TOKEN_GROUPS".  You should be able to find some pinvoke sample if you have to do it in C#

Comment: TokenGroups work, but you need to query each group to get the group scope, so that's too much overhead.  There were a few examples on pinvoke, but none that I can understand... I wound up using tokensz.exe, redirected standardOutput, and parsed the string for what I need.  Thanks for your insight.